# How to do click outside on mobile iOS with Angular @HostListener

Tags: angular

**I do this, but on the mobile iPhone it does not work.
Works everywhere except iPhone**

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    public onClick(targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }

        const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(
            targetElement
        );
       if (!clickedInside && targetElement.className.indexOf('title') === -1) {
           console.log('click outside');
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

After some research, this should work

```
@HostListener('document:touchend', ['$event'])
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
  if (this.container.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
    // this is inside
  } else {
    // this is outside
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this way works on iPhone 5, the difference is using container variable which is ViewChild ref to the wrapped element in your component

TS:

```
@ViewChild('container') container;

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  outClickHandler(event: Event): void {
    if (!this.container.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      console.log('click outside');
    }
  }
```

and HTML

```
<div #container>
  ...content
</div>
```